# Proof of $\big|\int_E (f\cdot g)(x) \text{d}x\big| \leq [\int_E |f(x)|^p\text{d}x]^{(1/p)} \cdot [\int_E |g(x)| ^q\text{d}x]^{(1/q)}$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, riemann-integration, young-inequality

The answer to this question is given in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223651/int-ab-fxgx-dx-leq-left-int-ab-fxp-dx-right-frac1p-left), but I cannot fill the gaps between the accepted answer, so here is what I have done with the guide of @Raito.

**My work:**

By Young's inequality, we do know that

$$|f\cdot g| \leq \frac{|f|^p}{p} + \frac{ |g|^q}{ q} = \frac{\lambda^p |f|^p}{p} + \frac{ |g|^q}{\lambda^q q}.$$
Now choose $\lambda = \left(\dfrac{|g|^q }{|f|^p }\right)^{\frac{1 }{p+q } },$
then we have 
$$= |f| \cdot |g|.$$

Now, we also do know that

$$\bigg|\int_E f\cdot g \ \text{d}x\bigg| \leq \int_E |f\cdot g| \text{d}x \leq \int_E \frac{|f|^p}{p} \text{d}x + \int_E \frac{ |g|^q}{ q} \text{d}x \leq \int_E |f| \text{d}x \cdot \int_E |g| \text{d}x $$

**But after that I couldn't figure out how to get the $1/p$ and $1/q$ powers of those integrals.**

Comment: Hint: WLOG, we can assume that $||f||_p=||g||_q = 1$.

Comment: @Raito Is there any different way of showing this ? I mean the answer does not even uses the things that we have computed yesterday.

Comment: Yes, treat $\bar{f}$ in the answer as $f$ in your question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter without assuming $||f||_p=||g||_q = 1$ or anything similar to that, I still do not see how to proceed.

Comment: @GNUSupporter By the way, What is the explicit definition of $||f||_p$ ?

Comment: $$\left[\int_E |f(x)|^p\text{d}x\right]^{(1/p)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\widetilde{f}=\dfrac{|f|}{\|f\|_{p}}$, $\widetilde{g}=\dfrac{|g|}{\|g\|_{q}}$, then $\|\widetilde{f}\|_{p}=\|\widetilde{g}\|_{q}=1$. And 
\begin{align*}
\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}&\leq\dfrac{\widetilde{f}^{p}}{p}+\dfrac{\widetilde{g}^{q}}{q},\\
\int\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}dx&\leq\dfrac{1}{p}\int\widetilde{f}^{p}dx+\dfrac{1}{q}\int\widetilde{g}^{q}dx\\
\int\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}dx&\leq\dfrac{1}{p}\|\widetilde{f}\|_{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}\|\widetilde{g}\|_{q}\\
\int\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}dx&\leq\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\int\widetilde{f}\widetilde{g}dx&\leq 1,\\
\int|fg|dx&\leq\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{q}.
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the explicit definition of $||f||_p$ ?

Comment: no, it is $(\int_E |f|^p dx)^{1/p}$